# Compare String with String (Byte array from DatagramPacket)

Tags: java, string, udp, arrays, datagram

So I've been asked to create a UDP messaging app. I have two clients that are run from the command line on the same computer, and I am trying to get each client to break out of a while loop when it receives the String `"exit"` from the other client, so they both terminate simultaneously.

`String input` is created above this code so if this client inputs `"exit"`, the while is skipped (This works fine!).

```
DatagramSocket receiveSocket = new DatagramSocket(8000); //Port 8000
byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[65508];

while(!input.equals("exit")) {

    DatagramPacket packetToReceive = new DatagramPacket(receiveBuffer, receiveBuffer.length);

    receiveSocket.receive(packetToReceive);
    receiveBuffer = packetToReceive.getData();

    String receivedMessage = new String(receiveBuffer);


    if(!receivedMessage.equals("exit")) {   
        System.out.println("A says: " + receivedMessage);
    }
    else {
        input = "exit";
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I cannot get `!receivedMessage.equals("exit")` to equate to `false`, even though when I do a `System.out.println(receivedMessage)`, I get `"exit"`. They look exactly the same but obviously aren't.
I have tried forcing encoding such as...

```
String receivedMessage = new String(receiveBuffer, "UTF-8");
```

...but nothing works. I've tried many other combinations of forced encoding, plus converting `receivedMessage` to a Byte array, char array etc. to compare, and I've checked for whitespace on either side of `receivedMessage`, still nothing.

Any help would be appreciated. It has to be something small I'm missing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is possibly the problem with the **receiveBuffer** size. Currently you are sending "exit" in the packet, which is small enough to fit in **65508** bytes. So, the remaining bytes in the **receiveBuffer** are simply empty or contain special characters. That is why when you receive the packet and get the data into a string, the remaining bytes are also there in the string.

You can either use `contains()` instead of `equals()` for comparing the string or you can put only the desired bytes containing the actual message into the receiveBuffer. Here is one of the possible way to achieve that:

```
receiveSocket.receive(packetToReceive);
receiveBuffer = new byte[packetToReceive.getLength()];
System.arraycopy(packetToReceive.getData(), packetToReceive.getOffset(), receiveBuffer, 0, packetToReceive.getLength());

String receivedMessage = new String(receiveBuffer);

if(!receivedMessage.equals("exit")) {   
    System.out.println("A says: " + receivedMessage);
}
else {
    input = "exit";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Using `contains()` instead did the trick as it's only a proof of concept college assignment, but I'm glad to know why `equals()` wouldn't work. Thought I was going mad!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are some leading or trailing spaces in receivedMessage. Try to trim it.

Answer (score 0):

```
receiveSocket.receive(packetToReceive);
receiveBuffer = packetToReceive.getData();
String receivedMessage = new String(receiveBuffer);
```

The problem is here. You're ignoring the length of the received packet. The last two lines can be changed to just this:

```
String receivedMessage = new String(packetToReceive.getData(), packetToReceive.getOffset(), packetToReceive.getLength());
```